# How to properly measure the temperature of meat with a meat thermometer

Tags: meat, temperature, thermometer

I have a Thermapen meat thermometer that I use for precise temperature measurement. Although it's easy to read and fast, I'm not exactly sure how to take readings.

With a large piece of meat with consistent temperature throughout its quite easy, like a braise or meat in a stew. I am having trouble with burgers though, they are much thinner, and the temperature is very inconsistent, so it's difficult to know whether it has reached medium rare or medium or whatever.

Comment: See here - the accepted answer uses a burger as a specific example. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/how-do-you-correctly-use-a-meat-thermometer?rq=1